# Where can I find the English translation of the Vedas?

Tags: vedas, translation-request

I am aware of Griffith's translation. But I am not very satisfied with that. Is there any other translation available?

Comment: Max Mueller also did a translation. You can google his name to find.

Comment: It's always better to read translations of Indian Authors rather than in English by foreign authors.

Comment: Yes, that is why I think Tulsi Ram's translation from Arya Samaj is very important. But the problem is I am not able to find Tulsi Ram's translation of Rig Veda and Atharva Veda!

Comment: Max Mueller RigVeda Samhitha  is available in several state libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a few links!

Rig Veda:

[Rig Veda Samhita by Max Muller](https://archive.org/details/rigvedasanhitas00mlgoog) Thanks to Swami Vishwananda for this link!

**One of the best translation along with detailed commentary.**
[The Rigveda: 3-Volume Set by Stephanie W. Jamison and Joel P. Brereton](https://www.amazon.in/dp/B00MN96ZHS/ref=dp-kindle-redirect?_encoding=UTF8&btkr=1)

Yajur Veda:
This pdf file has watermarks.
[Yajur Veda English translated by Dr Tulsi Ram. Arya Samaj e library](http://elibrary.thearyasamaj.org/elib/book/eLb_319/)

Sama Veda:
This pdf file has watermarks.
[Sama Veda English translated by Dr Tulsi Ram. Arya Samaj e library](http://elibrary.thearyasamaj.org/elib/book/eLb_318/)

Atharva Veda: translated by Dr Tulsi Ram

https://archive.org/details/susmitaroychowdhury512_gmail_20180202

**All volumes of four Vedas - The best collection:**

To get the English translation of all 4 Vedas by Dr Tulsi Ram, please go to the following link. Dr Tulsi Ram's translation is the best. By the way, the filenames are in Bengali, but the books are in English! So do not get confused.

https://archive.org/details/susmitaroychowdhury512_gmail

These pdf files have an annoying yellow background colour. However, with any pdf editor (for example, PDF XChange editor) you can easily remove all background colour and can get pure white background! Otherwise, file qualities are excellent. Files are small and they do not have any watermark. Most importantly files are not protected, which means you can annotate these pdf files easily!

Answer (score 1):

sacred texts.com provide various hindu scriptures to read free and downloadable too.

Translator: Ralph T. H. Griffith, 1896

link— http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/

1-[**Rigveda**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/index.htm)

2-[**samaveda**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sv.htm)

3-[**white yajurveda/shukla yajurveda**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/wyv/index.htm)

3-[**black yajurveda/krishna yajurveda or taittrayi samhita**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/yv/index.htm)

4-[**atharvaveda**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/av/index.htm)

for download in english and hindi :— http://www.patheos.com/blogs/hindu2/2016/03/vedas-the-4-vedas-in-hindi-english-telugu-pdf-download/

&

for total english:— https://archive.org/details/FourVedasEnglishTranslation?_e_pi_=

Comment: Thanks for uploading the links to Griffith's translations. I was actually looking for other translations. But anyways these links are also useful.

Comment: @amritendu check last download links they are not all of Ralph T.H. griffith it was by mistake set to direct download but i edited and made it detailed one.

Comment: The OP is  already   aware of  Griffith's translation. And want the other ones.