# How did this world got manifested as per Vedas?

Tags: vedas, creation, universe

According to Puranas, the world is created/manifested as per respective supreme deities. Also different sects have different philosophies. But my question is, how did this universe manifested as per Vedas?

Note: please do not give reference of Vedantas. Only Vedas reference is acceptable.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by Vedanta. If you mean Upanishads, Upanishads are part and parcel of the vedas. If you mean not Upanishads, see Rig Veda x.129.1-7 See also https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/13969/what-is-the-need-of-creation/13990#13990

Comment: for translations of Rig Veda see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23845/where-can-i-find-the-english-translation-of-the-vedas/23849#23849

Comment: @Swami ji Yes only Vedic, not even Upanishad.

Comment: @sriman Nope read question again.

Comment: @Sarva No! My question is very specific to Vedas.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto That question also covers Vedas and consists an answer written from RigVeda. The question you are asking is already covered.

Comment: @Sarva link to that answer please.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto: please go through the answer  (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/35174/3869)

Comment: [Answer 1](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/8525/5212) which has Upanishad as well as Rigveda. [Answer 2](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/9332/5212) with Sanskrit verses with svara markings.

Comment: Read the last part of [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/8525/277). Nasadiya Sukta is from RigVeda

Comment: @Paṇḍyā♦ @Sarva Please cast duplicate vote